# window.location.href using GET when I need POST

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following script, a few lines up from the bottom I have a `window.location.href` which posts the reults from my form though the address bar. This is very messy and I would like to use POST instead of GET, any ideas anyone ?

```
<script language="javascript">
function OnChangedUsername()
{
  if(document.signup.newuserid.value == "")
  {
    document.signup.btnCheckAvailability.disabled = true;
  }
  else
  {
    document.signup.btnCheckAvailability.disabled = false;
  }
}
function createRequestObject() {
  var ro;
  var browser = navigator.appName;
  if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
    ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }else{
    ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  return ro;
}

var http = createRequestObject();

function sndReq() {
  http.open('get', 'password_check.asp?emailaddress=<%Response.Write(emailaddress)%>&check=<%Response.Write(check)%>&password_check='+document.signup.newuserid.value);
  http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
  http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() {
  if(http.readyState == 4){
    var response = http.responseText;
    var update = new Array();

    if(response.indexOf('|' != -1)) {
      update = response.split('|');
      document.getElementById("username_chk").innerHTML = update[0];


      if(document.getElementById("username_chk").innerHTML == "Ok") {
        window.location.href='detailsupdate.asp?username=<%Response.Write(sUsername)%>&check=<%Response.Write(check)%>&EmailAddress='+document.signup.EmailAddress.value+'&Address='+document.signup.Address.value+'&Address1='+document.signup.Address1.value+'&Address2='+document.signup.Address2.value+'&City='+document.signup.City.value+'&PostalCode='+document.signup.PostalCode.value+'&Country='+document.signup.Country.value+'&WorkPhone='+document.signup.WorkPhone.value+'&HomePhone='+document.signup.HomePhone.value+'&MobilePhone='+document.signup.MobilePhone.value+'&FaxNumber='+document.signup.FaxNumber.value+'&AlternativePhone='+document.signup.AlternativePhone.value+'&OO='+document.signup.OO.checked+'&Workshop='+document.signup.Workshop.checked+'&Raised='+document.signup.Raised.checked+'&Ground='+document.signup.Ground.checked+'&pd='+document.signup.newuserid.value+'&Tram='+document.signup.Tram.checked;
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make a POST request with the response rendered directly into the browser window is to use a form (which you generate with DOM) and submit it (which you can likewise do through DOM).

The alternative is to use XMLHttpRequest (or some other Ajax technique) and render the response with DOM.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass form data as GET data. You can specify the method as POST.

```
<form action="script.asp" method="post">
   ...
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You also should not be using `window.location.href`. This is very ugly. When you submit the form (click the submit button) it will POST your form data to script.asp.

Another way to submit your form is to submit it via DOM. `document.forms[0].submit();`