# window.location.href with POST instead of GET (or equivalent effect)

Tags: javascript, rest, http

I'd like to reload a web page after supplying new parameters to it via POST in the same way as would be possible with an HTML `form` but from within JavaScript (inside an HTML page, but outside the context of a `form`).

Is this possible as HTTP POST instead of GET request (kind of `XMLHttpRequest` plus replace the currently shown document)? How could I replace the document, if `XMLHttpRequest` must be employed (instead of `window.location.href`)? The second question has been partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325358/window-location-href-using-get-when-i-need-post).

Comment: You basically want programmatical form submit , check Related questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I have always done this (with jquery) is this.

```
var $form=$(document.createElement('form')).css({display:'none'}).attr("method","POST").attr("action","URLHERE");
var $input=$(document.createElement('input')).attr('name','FIRST NAME HERE').val("FIRST VALUE HERE");
var $input2=$(document.createElemet('input')).attr('name','SECOND NAME HERE').val("SECOND VALUE HERE");
$form.append($input).append($input2);
$("body").append($form);
$form.submit();
```

Comment: POST and input numbering fixed, I copied this from one of my projects :D