# Redirect as a post

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

Maybe I am not approaching this correctly, but I have a page where the user submits data via ajax call, if that call succeeds I want to return to a specific page (the previous page).  What I was hoping to do is redirect as a post call, therefore the logic was going to be if I came to the page as a post I know that the call was successful and can do some action, if the call was a get then don't attempt to do that action.

The part where I am stuck is the only code I found to do a redirect on the client is `window.location.href`.  So is there an equivalent method to redirect as a post (or for that matter any other verb)?

Comment: If you're not limited to using a verb, you could always append a parameter to your URL and check for it to determine how you got there (i.e. `window.location.href = '/your/page?successfulPost=true'`).

Comment: Sorry I did not explain that well, I do not want to use querystring because  I am concern that the user will bookmark the saved state of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hidden form with `method=POST` and put the redirect link in the `action` attribute and submit that.
Alternatively, just redirect with a get request and a query param, something like `example.com?redirection=1`. Now just check if the redirection `param == 1` and use that as a condition to do your stuff

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid querystring if a user book marked the page but I did find this a minute ago, just trying it now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697338/window-location-href-with-post-instead-of-get-or-equivalent-effect

Answer (score 1):

The only way to post data is via an HTML form attached to the DOM.  If your page doesn't already have a form you can use, you can do this with a bit of jquery like this:

```
var f = $('<form method="post" action="https://SomeDomain.com/Somepage"></form>');
f.html('<input type="hidden" name="Param1" value="Value1" /><input type="hidden" name="Param2" value="Value2" />');
f.appendTo($('body')); // required for submission to work in Firefox
f.submit();
```